# Injection text in condition Native Query - JPA

Tags: spring-boot, jpa

I need injection the code in my SQL. I used Spring Boot and JPA.

I trying send by parameter, but not have success. I dont know how add text in @Query.

My Repository:

```
@Query(nativeQuery = true,
            value = "SELECT viw.* \n" +
                    "FROM  viwFinanceiro_Extrato_DocumentosPesquisar viw \n" +
                    "WHERE viw.CodigoGNPessoas IN (:CodigoGNPessoas) AND \n" +
                    "(viw.DocumentoDataEmissao >= :DataInicial AND viw.DocumentoDataEmissao <= :DataFinal) AND \n" +
                    "viw.CodigoFinanceiroFNDocumentosSituacaoFinanceira IN (:CodigoFinanceiroFNDocumentosSituacaoFinanceira) AND \n" +
                    "viw.CodigoFinanceiroFNTiposDocumentos IN (:CodigoFinanceiroFNTiposDocumentos) AND \n" +
                    "viw.DocumentoDigitado = CASE WHEN :NumeroDocumento IS NULL OR :NumeroDocumento = '' THEN viw.DocumentoDigitado ELSE :NumeroDocumento END AND \n" +
                    "viw.DocumentoVerificado = CASE WHEN :IndicadorDocumentoVerificado = 3 THEN viw.DocumentoVerificado ELSE :IndicadorDocumentoVerificado END  AND \n" +
                    " ************ HERE CODE FROM WHERE ************  \n" +
                    " ORDER BY viw.DocumentoDataEmissao")
    Collection<ViwFinanceiroExtratoDocumentosPesquisar> load(@Param("CodigoGNPessoas") List<Long> CodigoGNPessoas,
                                                             @Param("DataInicial") String DataInicial,
                                                             @Param("DataFinal") String DataFinal,
                                                             @Param("CodigoFinanceiroFNDocumentosSituacaoFinanceira") List<Integer> CodigoFinanceiroFNDocumentosSituacaoFinanceira,
                                                             @Param("CodigoFinanceiroFNTiposDocumentos")  List<Integer> CodigoFinanceiroFNTiposDocumentos,
                                                             @Param("NumeroDocumento") String NumeroDocumento,
                                                             @Param("IndicadorDocumentoVerificado") Integer IndicadorDocumentoVerificado)
```

Comment: What exception are you getting?